# Ruby Rails form_for on each loop not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This form is not working. My goal is to submit both fields. Please help thanks!

table

```
  create_table "products", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "count"
  end

  create_table "customers", :force => true do |t|
    t.decimal   "money"
  end
```

form

```
    <% @product.each do |product| %>
        <%= form_for(product) do |f| %>
            <%= f.number_field :count %>
            <%= f.number_field :money %>
            <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :count
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

Comment: Where is the submit button?

Comment: Can you be more specific: What is not working precisely? You say you want to submit both fields, but what is happening exactly; is it sending only one of the two, is it sending nothing, or something else entirely?

Comment: throws an error undefined method `money' for #<Products:0x61c28e8>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are creating a form for a `Product` model, and adding a number field for `money`.  The problem is that your `Product` model **does not** have a `money` property, your `Customer` model does.  You'll need to read more about [Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) to submit both models at once.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `money` is an attribute of `Customer` model (based on your migration file)